# Should we start a new tag encouraging multiple answers to a fun problems to solve?

Tags: discussion, answers, tags

In an effort to make the community here a bit more fun, I propose that we use a new tag that would conform to a set of standards (maybe a complete template to start a new post) outlined in the discussion here with you all about it.

These tagged posts will **define a problem that has many possible solutions, as a exercise for those looking to skill up in Substrate can take on**.

Rules about how to post spoilers in answers should likely be in place so that opening the post doesn't in itself imply any solution thou answers will link to or have collapsible sections that describes their approach & solution.

**What should we call this tag? And what should the standards (or full templates) be for asking one of these puzzle/challenge/open-ended-problem questions be?**

Comment: I would also love to see examples of this kid of behavior in other SE communities... is anyone here are of any? If not, what about other communities that center on forum-like platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not seem like what StackExchange should be used for.

I would not, for example, encourage people to post random open-ended questions or puzzles in this community.

StackExchange is a community for helping people get the answer to questions they have about a topic. As soon as we start making it a game for people to post random questions, we then take away from helping those that actually need help.

Comment: Essentially, yes - SE is here to answer specific, narrow questions and answers about a topic that people actually face. While there's some room on Meta for more fun pursuits (though not likely the one in this question), this sort of thing should not be part of the main site. SE sites are not forums for discussion and puzzles are better scoped to sites designed for that purpose - either on SE (e.g. [codegolf.se] or [puzzling.se]) or offsite entirely.